# Camera module survivability questions

Tags: camera, electronics, troubleshooting

I have a camera module which was working fine without the two infrared (IR) lights:

[image: infrared camera].

Today, I decided to place on the IR lights:

- turned off Pi
- attached the lights and rescrewed the camera on its mounting
- turned on Pi

Nevertheless, Pi cannot recognize the camera, even without the IR lights (which were glowing before). I have tried resitting the ribbon, converting to legacy (but no `raspvid` there, only with `libcamera-vid`).

- What could go wrong? How can I repair the electronic circuit of the camera module?
- Is it possible that some kind of short-circuit happened? It
  shouldn't, but if yes, which one is most likely to fail, raspberry
  pi's side of circuitry or the camera's?
- My take is that a   short-circuit shouldn't cause damage because the voltage is low, but
  I'm just an amateur, is my intuition correct?
- What can I do to troubleshoot the problem? Of course it's not the cost of the camera module (although it hurts a bit) but I ask more for learning purposes.

Comment: your question is not Raspberry Pi specific

Answer (score 0):

The problem is fixed. However, if anyone can answer the questions of electronics survivability for Raspberry Pi/Arduino type of projects please feel free, since I have not found concrete online answers.

The problem was that when I was screwing the super-tiny hex nuts a corner of one of them was making a tiny "invisible contact" with a pin of a component. During all my tests there was a short-circuit, and this didn't damage the camera nor the Pi. Unbelievable, as a certain Australian would say... [image: Invisible contact]

Comment: I use nylon screws and nuts for mounting my camera to eliminate this problem.